# Reflect a object along x and y axis

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

Need to reflect a group containing objects as shown in picture.

I have a sample image for what i have done in my current progress.

[image]

Objective: Reflection of objects should be done along x and y axis as per the below image

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple code looks like this:

```
copiedDisplayObject.scaleY = -1;
copiedDisplayObject.alpha = 0.4;
```

That is really a specific example of reflection over a line, where the line happens to be the x axis. (ie y = 0x + 0) If you want to reflect over another line, you can use a matrix. The code below preserves previous transformations on the display object, and reflects it over a line passing through the origin.

```
var m:Number = 0.25; //example slope -- from line: y = mx + 0
var tmpMatrix = copiedDisplayObject.transform.matrix;
var relectMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix(1-m*m, 2*m, 2*m, m*m -1);
tmpMatrix.concat(relectMatrix);
copiedDisplayObject.transform.matrix = tmpMatrix;
```

I found the matrix formula here: [math.stackexchange question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/525082/reflection-across-a-line)

Comment: thanx its more usefull because i have five conditions like object should be reflected along x-axis , y-axis, x=1,x=y,x=-y...

Comment: The matrix will work for non-vertical lines. You will have to detect the vertical case and use scaleX *= -1 or use the matrix for this case (ie new Matrix(-1,0,0,1) )

Answer (score 1):

Very easy approach: for reflection you should have copy of the object that will be reflected.
Reflection could be made by `myReflectedObject.scaleY = -1`

```
myReflectedObject.scaleY = -1;
myReflectedObject.alpha = 0.4;
//manage Y position accordingly
```